# Using Cordova, is there a way to reference native icons?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm using Cordova 3.5 to build an app which contains a menu with pretty standard items in the list (home, contacts, etc.), and I want to use the native menu icons whenever possible. I believe those icons are already on the device as part of the OS, but I don't know if Cordova gives me a way to reference them.

I suppose I'd need to write a Javascript function to choose the right file name based on the platform, e.g.:

```
// this is pseudocode
var icon = '';
if (platform === 'android') {
  icon = 'some/path/home.png';
} else {
  icon = 'other/path/icon.home.png';
  // or maybe a function such as the following exists:
  // icon = cordova.getNativeIcon('icon.home.png');
}

$('.selector').css('background-image', icon);
```

Alternatively, I may be able to make do by referencing the files in CSS, e.g.:

```
.android .home-icon {
  background-image: url('some/path/home.png');
}
.ios .home-icon {
  background-image: url('other/path/icon.home.png');
}
```

So, how do folks handle this sort of thing in Cordova? Is there a function I can use to access native icons? Are folks just copying them into their projects? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with Cordova, then you'll be working inside a web view provided by the host OS and you won't have direct access to any artwork. I've found that using icon fonts and CSS "themes" to work well enough, but that approach will replicate artwork already provided. There's extra work involved with theming for iOS 6 vs iOS 7 or 8, for example, but it's not as bad as it sounds.

IBM does have an article on partitioning your view between native and web controls, but it sounds a bit cumbersome. More details here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/ios_combining_native_and_web_controls_in_cordova_based_applications

Comment: so short answer: no.

Best would be to find an icon font you like that matches closely and use that. We use Icon 8 for our icons and icomoon to keep the file trim to only those we use.